# How to extract and limit the length of extracted value in JSON query?

Tags: json

I have this JSON:

```
{
  "Id": "1",
  "translations": [
    {
      "locale": "en",
      "shortName": "Cologne",
      "longName": "FC Cologne"
    },
    {
      "locale": "tr",
      "shortName": "Köln",
      "longName": "Köln"
    },
    {
      "locale": "de-de",
      "shortName": "Köln",
      "longName": "1. FC Köln"
    },
    {
      "locale": "nl-nl",
      "shortName": "1 FC Köln",
      "longName": "1 FC Köln"
    },
    {
      "locale": "cs",
      "shortName": "1. FC Köln",
      "longName": "1. FC Köln"
    },
    {
      "locale": "it",
      "shortName": "Colonia",
      "longName": "Colonia"
    }
  ],
  "name": "1. FC Cologne",
  "d": 2
}
```

and I would like to get an array using JSON query like this:(the first two characters of all locale values):

[
    "en",
    "tr",
    "de",
    "nl",
    "cs",
    "it"
]

When I use this query:

```
$.translations[*].locale
```

The result is: (de-de and nl-nl are not desired, I want de and nl):

[
    "en",
    "tr",
    "de-de",
    "nl-nl",
    "cs",
    "it"
]

and if use this JSON query:

```
$.translations[*].locale[0]
```

It gives me the all first characters:

[
    "e",
    "t",
    "d",
    "n",
    "c",
    "i"
]

Is there any query available to give me my desired result? I would appreciate any help! I check my JSON query here: http://www.jsonquerytool.com/

Comment: what's your operation system?

Comment: I would like to use this query in a test in JMeter. I work on a Mac book. How is it important? Any doc or info would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript query: `input.translations.map(x => x.locale.slice(0,2))`

Tried here: http://www.jsonquerytool.com/#/JavaScript

Choose `Query type` = `JavaScript`